# How does Han communicate with Chewbacca?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars

Ever since the character was introduced I struggled to understand how Chewbacca communicates with everyone. His grunts sound more or less the same every time but somehow everyone seems to "know" what he is trying say?

As per this [wikipedia article,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wookiee)

> Wookiees are capable of understanding Galactic Basic, but generally
>   none are able to speak it because of the structure of Wookiee vocal
>   cords

and

> His human partner, Han Solo, also shows knowledge of Shyriiwook, or
>   can at least understand Chewbacca

**If Chewbacca is a wookie and can't speak Shyriiwook, how is Han able to understand him?**

Comment: Chewbacca *does* speak Shyriiwook, that's the point...

Comment: Shyriiwook is the Wookiee language, many are *also* able to understand Galactic Basic.

Comment: Do you have a dog? Same concept (albeit Chewie is a much higher life form than your typical dog). Dogs understands your verbalized commands, but can't speak them himself. You, in return, likely 'understand' some of your dogs grunts and looks and such. Two different languages, but you both understand each other.

Answer (score 9):

> So if Chewbacca is a wookie and can't speak Shyriiwook, how is Han able to understand him?

I'm not sure where this misunderstanding of that article came from, but this statement isn't correct.

As a Wookie, Chewbacca *understands* Galactic Basic, but he's incapable of speaking it. Instead, he speaks the native Wookie language, Shyriiwook. Those grunts that sound the same to us *are* the Wookie language -- that's just what it sounds like.

As a human, Han Solo *understands* Shyriiwook (mostly), but he's incapable of speaking it. Instead, he typically speaks Galactic Basic.

Since they both understand each other's language, they can communicate just fine.

Comment: This has been a fairly common theme throughout most of Star Wars, and I'd venture to say it simply makes things easier. You can just throw up subtitles if the audience really needs to know what's being said, or just have fun with it like Han always replying back to Chewie. C-3P0 was the perfect translator to have as well, because no one will question a robot that looks incredibly advanced from being able to hear and speak millions of languages in a technologically advanced galaxy.

Comment: true; though not everyone understands everyone else. there seems to be a pretty broad level of understanding of human languages, fewer people appear to understand Shyriiwook or droid binary...

Comment: @MattD It's actually a theme so inherent to *Star Wars* that it was part of the millions of *Star Wars* reminiscences in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, which drove the weirdness of the Chewie-Han communication ad absurdum.

Comment: Right, Galactic Basic is the lingua franca of their galaxy, much the way English is becoming the lingua franca of our planet, but there are still plenty of people who won't understand, and no way for them to learn the apparently 6 million languages that exist, if C-3PO is to be fully believed (and why would he lie?).

Comment: @MattD Well, I'd wager most of those 6 million dialects are some kind of binary droid crap, though, like the binary language of moisture vaporators.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Possibly, but regardless I feel it's a nice way to handle the naturally many languages that would be spoken in that galaxy without bogging story down in the requirement of translation equipment or what have you.

Comment: @MattD Of course, that aspect was always very interesting to me, too. And it just feels very natural. R2 is the other great example.

Comment: I always thought it was harsh that Greedo was only in the film for 5 minutes and gets subtitles whereas Chewbacca is in the whole series and doesn't.

Comment: @Richard in a way, we *all* understand Chewie...with or without subtitles.